# Overlapping Partition table

Tags: partition, table

I'm so done with this, i have this 64GB sd card and i just don't know any more. when i format it the data and partition tables just stay there. :'(

all i want is for a blank drive, i've got a backup of the data already.

```
hartofwave@HartofWave-Flaming-Blade-GTI:~ > sudo fdisk -l -u /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 63.9 GB, 63864569856 bytes                                                                                                                                                                                                    
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 60906 cylinders, total 124735488 sectors                                                                                                                                                                         
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes                                                                                                                                                                                        
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes                                                                                                                                                                                            
Disk identifier: 0x6b736964                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

This doesn't look like a partition table                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Probably you selected the wrong device.                                                                                                                                                                                                      

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System                                                                                                                                                                               
/dev/sdb1   ?  1701998624  3331515282   814758329+  74  Unknown                                                                                                                                                                              
/dev/sdb2   ?  1330184192  1869160479   269488144   65  Novell Netware 386
/dev/sdb3   ?   538989391  1937352302   699181456   53  OnTrack DM6 Aux3
/dev/sdb4   ?  3909118566  3909183904       32669+  bb  Boot Wizard hidden

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

-

```
hartofwave@HartofWave-Flaming-Blade-GTI:~ > sudo parted /dev/sdb unit s print
Model: TS-RDF5 SD Transcend (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 124735488s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End         Size        File system  Flags
 1      0s     124735487s  124735488s  fat32
```

-

```
hartofwave@HartofWave-Flaming-Blade-GTI:~ > sudo mount -l
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
```

-

```
Hartofwave@HartofWave-Flaming-Blade-GTI:~ > sudo mkfs.ext2 /dev/sdb
mke2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/sdb is entire device, not just one partition!
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
3899392 inodes, 15591936 blocks
779596 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
476 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

-

```
Hartofwave@HartofWave-Flaming-Blade-GTI:~ > sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1 count=512
[sudo] password for hartofwave: 
512+0 records in
512+0 records out
512 bytes (512 B) copied, 0.00280728 s, 182 kB/s
```

-

```
hartofwave@HartofWave-Flaming-Blade-GTI:~ > sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
[sudo] password for hartofwave: 

Command (m for help): o
Building a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x0cf4e32b.
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
After that, of course, the previous content won't be recoverable.

Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 4 will be corrected by w(rite)

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

-

Update

So I've still not got a fix, one thing i would like to know is why after making and writing change are they undone after the device is refreshed or the pc is rebooted?
Does anyone  have anything i can try??

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
[sudo] password for hartofwave: 

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.25.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): v
Partition 1: overlaps partition 2.
Partition 1: overlaps partition 3.
Total allocated sectors 4866404289 greater than the maximum 124735488.
```

Comment: You don't have a partition table on there. `fdisk` is getting confused; `parted` is telling you you have written a fat32 filesystem directly to the disk without having a partition table. Can you mount `/dev/sdb`? What are you trying to do? You can use `mkfs` to format it (e.g. `mkfs /dev/sdb`) if you don't need a partition table, or you can use `fdisk` or `parted` to write a proper partition table and then `mkfs /dev/sdb1` etc. to format the partitions.

Comment: I think /dev/sdb is mounted, i can browse it in dolphin. ive add mkfs out put and nothing has changed still says fat32 and has all the data in it. Im trying to wipe everything so i can use it again.

Comment: If it's mounted, you must unmount it first, otherwise it will get confused. Also, are you sure you're writing to the right disk? What's the output of `mount`?

Comment: it was, ive unmounted it and formatted as ext4 and it comes back as fat32

Comment: `Building a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x6fef764e.
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
After that, of course, the previous content won't be recoverable.


Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 4 will be corrected by w(rite)`

So fdisk gave me this, and when i write nothing changes

Comment: Just remove the existing partition table using `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1 count=512` and then create a new one with `fdisk` (use `o` to create an empty DOS partition table). Maybe remove the disk or reboot the device between those two actions to remove the OS cache of the old partition table.

Comment: ive done dd and fdisk, added the output to the op. nothing has changed

Comment: `(gpartedbin:2959): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 20854 was not found when attempting to remove it. File system is reporting the free space as 1500614 clusters, not 1643491 clusters.`

Resizing with gparted kicks out this in the terminal and crashes gparted (gui)